# function not defined onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code:

```
<script>
    function logout() {
        var logoutbtn = document.getElementById('logouttext');
        logoutbtn.innerText = "Byebye!";
        setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "/";
            }
            1000);
    }
</script>
<div id="Logout" class="waves-effect logout" onclick="logout()">
    <p id="logouttext">LOGOUT</p>
</div>
```

Now when I click on the logout div, it prints in the console that the function logout is not defined, however, when I change the function to only contain `window.location.href = "/";` it does work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your JS (a missing comma), which prevents it from being parsed and hence is not available in the onclick handler. Look at the console for some more details.

Comment: `}1000);` = `},1000);` for correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to put comma `,` before the 1000 milliseconds .

Below a working code :

```js
function logout() {
    var logoutbtn = document.getElementById('logouttext');
    logoutbtn.innerText = "Byebye!";
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "/";
    },1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="Logout" class="waves-effect logout" onclick="logout()"><p id="logouttext">LOGOUT</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! Forgot it there..

Comment: Questions that are a simple typographical errors shouldn't be answered, they should be flagged and closed.

Comment: A little sidenote: the second argument is not in seconds, but in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma inside the setTimeout function before 1000.

Just change the setTimeout function with this following lines:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "/";
},1000);
```